# Category is disbled in admin side but still showing in frontend

Tags: admin, category, frontend, category-tree

Category disabled from backend still showing in frontend. Even if there are no products available in that category and disabled. Enable category and include in menu options are turned off, but still showing. Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

Flush cache from the admin or run the below command.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Or check any third-party cache configure with the store. If used then needs flush it.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands and check

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```